# change color of xtype text in extjs4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, xtype

I need to change the color of the text below. Everything else in the style field works except for the text color.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
{
                            xtype: 'text',

                            text: "Logged in as:",
                            textAlign:'left',
                            style : "color:#3E546B;font-style:italic;font-family: tahoma, arial, verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;",
                            width: 140,
                            handler: function() {
                                document.location.href="";
                            }
                        },
```

EDIT. I am not using a form panel, i am using xtype:text inside a container.

http://jsfiddle.net/nCkZN/4/  (this still uses form panel. But this is to show the text color does not change)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [fieldStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-fieldStyle) instead of `style`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/nCkZN/)

---

**Update**

I confused 'text' and 'textfield'.

Now I've got it. The only way to change font style of `Ext.draw.Text` is to configure it with [styleSelector](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Text-cfg-styleSelector) (which has to refer to a valid css rule) like it is done in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/nCkZN/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Use The Fill in the Style As below use the type as text (Sprite) instead of using the Xtype as text

```
Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    items: [{
        type: "text",
        text: "Hello, Sprite!",
        fill: "green",
        font: "18px monospace"
    }]
});
```